# Review - automatically order based on expertise of reviewer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I notice when doing reviews that I am getting a lot of posts to review where I am unable to make a good judgement call for.

While some posts can be reviewed independent of the subject matter, often, I have to say "**Not Sure**".

Perhaps the order in which the posts are presented for review should be based on your tag counts given the tags attached to the question. So that initially, you get posts you are more likely to be able to review. This would save time when reviewing.

Comment: I think it already works this way now. At least I'm seeing much more questions that are relevant to my common tags than I have seen with the old review pages.

Comment: hmm, that's weird. "First Posts" contains 28k posts to be reviewed. But if that is the case, then there must be plenty that fit the tags I have answered, but I don't see much of those.

Comment: First posts are usually lacking the tags that adequately describe the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reviews already prioritizes posts based on the reviewer's favorite/ignored tags, as well as a certain number of *inferred* tag preferences. We will continue to refine and improve this mechanism, but essentially, this already exists.