# getting things done: make the number posts to review more manageable for a single reviewer

Tags: discussion, review

I was reviewing some late answers the other day and found it quite motivating to see number of items in the queue drop, to several hundreds left at some point.

Then I realized that that's one of the reasons why I rather work on suggested edits and low quality posts: you can work a bit and get the number down immediately; often it's possible to get it down to zero. You see your progress. It's manageable for a single person.

Please see [@Emrakul's answer to a related question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208238/155982) for a great analogy involving a beach and thousands of people.

[image: Getting things done]

> 6.6k late answers ... that seems impossible ... why even start?
>
> two suggested edits? I can do that, let's go!

Can we think of ideas to make these numbers manageable for simple reviewers like my self who like to [get things done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFGZj.png)?

*Update 2012 Oct 07*

I noted the numbers dropped significantly for late answers and low quality posts (for me at 1 and 4 at the moment). Does anybody know what changed?

*Update 2, 2012 Oct 07*

Ah, I see a filter option now. But modifying this filter does not not seem to change my number of actionable items in queue.

Suggestions:

- instead of 69.6k close votes, show the number of close votes in my top three tags
- instead of 17.5k first posts, show the number of first posts today, or the last couple of days, maybe even only in my Favorite Tags
- instead of 6.6k late answers, ignore those on tags in my Ignored Tags

This is somewhat vague at this stage. Do you have any suggestions so we can turn this into a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)?

#### example: an actionable Close Votes list

I'm aware that this is highly subjective, but for me, questions with 3 or 4 close votes in my top 5 tags (includes c#) makes a somewhat actionable list:

```
questionCount nrCloseVotes 
------------- ------------ 
2928          1            
1554          2            
531 << doable 3            
303 << doable 4            
1317          5            
82            6            
17            8            
1             9            
242           10
```

This was created using [this query on data.se](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81217/close-votes-in-my-top-tags). Maybe taking recent close votes into account would improve it.

#### example: actionable review task

[image: actionable review tasks]

Comment: related, but certainly not the same: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147686/review-automatically-order-based-on-expertise-of-reviewer | 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143854/more-aggressive-tag-match-between-reviewed-question-and-reviewer-activity

Comment: Well the Low Quality queue was actually similarly large...it seems the problem in clearing the Close queue is different. Not sure about new posts yet as it's pretty new. I do like the idea of prioritizing posts with more close votes, but I think those already show up first in the queue

Comment: Do you know what changes were made to get the nr of items in the low quality queue down?

Comment: As best I'm aware, it was really just lots of people reviewing and taking action. I think "taking action" is what's holding up the close vote queue. Not sure about the late answer/new posts queues, they're new so I'm not sure if they'll clear out the "backlog" or not yet.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145665/how-can-the-close-vote-review-queue-be-improved

Comment: Voting to close as it creates links between both questions - shog9 came up with idea close to yours.

Comment: Shog9's proposal is a good solution too and it addresses the same problem; so we might as well call this a duplicate.